# Copy folder & contents from inside zip into another location with QuaZIP?

Tags: c++, qt, directory, quazip

How would I go about copying a folder (and contents of the folder) from inside of a zip and moving the copied version of the folder to a different location?

I did not see any function in QuaZipDir that allows you to do this. I am hoping there is an easier way than parsing the files and then creating & writing.

For example if the zip looked like this:

- ZIP

  - Folder

    - File #1
    - File #2
    - File #3

I am, again, using **QuaZIP** with **Qt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, you could extract the files you want to copy to a temporary location on your hard disk and then copy them back to your zip file in the new location. After you copy to the new location from the temporary location, you can delete your temporary files. I think this is what many file compression tools do for file manipulation. Theoretically, you could copy the files to memory and then add them from memory into the new location in your zip file, but this could be dicey for larger files that won't fit in RAM. I would let the operating system handle the buffering to/from disk and not try to implement your own.

Comment: How would I extract the files? I can't seem to find any examples.

Comment: Take a look at http://quazip.sourceforge.net/classJlCompress.html. You will want to list the files in the zip file and then run extractFile or extractFiles on the file/files you want to extract.

Comment: Perfect. I don't know why I was avoiding that this whole time. I used extractDir on the zip, but it didn't extract the items inside of the directory which is inside the zip. Is this by design, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: You may need to recursively go through all sub-directories and run extractDir for each directory until all directories have been visited.

Comment: When I use extractDir on the directory, the directory is extracted, but the files inside are not. It is very odd.

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I had to remove line 421 in JlCompress.cpp. It was returning when it shouldn't be. Maybe I just used it wrong, but it's working great now! Thank you for suggesting to use the stuff in JlCompress.